# Ruby 1.8.7 versus Ruby 1.9+ performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

Recently I have been tasked with working on a fairly high volume Rails api (5k requests a second at peak).

Prior to this I've spent most of my coding efforts on Java applications, I'm just new to the world of Ruby/Rails.

At home I've been using the latest versions of Ruby/Rails to develop some small applications and get a feel for the language and framework.

The Rails application at work is built on Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.16 and to me it seems quite old and there are quite a few syntax and new features missing compared with the current versions I use at home.  I prefer the newer versions of ruby and rails.

I raised with my team about wanting to upgrade to newer/latest versions but I was told that newer versions of Ruby aren't 'production' ready.  Sadly due to my inexperience with Ruby I'm not really in a position to dispute this.

Any good articles/metrics showing either same or better performance with newer Ruby/Rails versions? Personally I would expect newer iterations of a language/framework to have better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These could help you

http://nerds.airbnb.com/upgrading-from-ree-187-to-ruby-193

http://blog.pothoven.net/2012/10/ruby-187-vs-193-performance.html

http://pulse.sportngin.com/news_article/show/156863?referrer_id=543230

note that ruby 2 has even better performance

Comment: That AirBNB link is fantastic, exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What your team probably meant instead was this:

> My Linux distribution of choice still ships Ruby 1.8.7 (or 1.8.6 if you are unlucky). As they haven't updated yet, I think it's not stable yet, but I have no hard data on this.

However, Linux distributions are very slow to change and it's rather hard for them to ensure that all software was updated to properly work on newer language versions.

That said, Ruby 1.8 is [nearing end-of-life](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/) rather fast. Right now, it only receives security updates anymore but no other bug fixes. In July 2013 it will be completely unsupported. This alone should be enough reason to upgrade your app rather soon.

As for the performance question: Ruby 1.9.3 is considered faster than Ruby 1.8.7 for most workloads. Ruby 2.0 is considered a bit faster than 1.9.3 but less so than the change from 1.8.7 to 1.9. That said, general performance advices are hard. You should check for yourself if these statements are true for your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,we are running Fedora release 15 for our app servers.  I had a spare box and installed the latest versions via RVM with no problems.  However it nearing end of life that fast is definitely a solid reason to switch!

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you are asking. You start off about perfomance, then you switch to "production-ready", then back to performance. Since you asked about performance twice, I'll assume that's what you meant.

The Ruby version makes no difference on the performance. Some people claim otherwise, but there haven't been any benchmarks actually demonstrating any sort of impact of the Ruby version on performance.

What *does* have a great impact on performance is the Ruby implementation you are using and the version of the implementation, as well as the environment that you are running it in. For example, JRuby is faster than MRI, JRuby 1.7 is faster than JRuby 1.6, JRuby 1.7 running on HotSpot is faster than JRuby 1.7 running on J9, JRuby 1.7 running on HotSpot 1.7 is faster than JRuby 1.7 running on HotSpot 1.6, JRuby 1.7 running on HotSpot 1.7 with the C2 compiler is faster than JRuby 1.7 running on HotSpot 1.7 with the C1 compiler, and so on.

Comment: Hi Jorg, you are correct it is slightly confusing. By production ready I just meant that the performance is stable and suitable for running critical applications.

Answer (score 0):

Support for Ruby 1.8.7 will be dropped completely after June 2013 as per [this](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/).

So it's better to upgrade to Ruby 1.9+ and Rails 3+. Checkout this [awesome post](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/07/the-way-to-rails-3/) about how to migrate from Rails 2 to Rails 3+

It is older for current releases of Rails, but as you have Rails 2 app, this post will help you finding differences between Rails 2 and Rails 3+ apps.

Also checkout [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) for awesome screencasts about how to upgrade to Rails 3, changes introduced in Rails 3 and Rails 4

Comment: Cheers Prathamesh, very useful!